# When I texture paint when I repeat and tile brush to get smaller it gets worse?

Tags: texture-painting

I'm texture painting, I've created a 2048x2048 brush. It's a nice brush, however I wanted to wanted the pattern the brush to create to be smaller. So I repeated in the texture mapping panel and the quality deteriorates.

I'd expect this when I'm making the texture bigger, however I wouldn't expect this to happen when making the  original brush smaller? And ideas if there's a fix to this?

Comment: Can you show some screen shots of the brush and settings and example of the result? I can't reproduce the problem and find a solution since I am unsure of what is happening here.

Comment: I've done a video it seem easier to demonstrate   https://youtu.be/7sCmsh77fcM

Comment: What size is your paint target/canvas resolution? Here I got the same issues when working with a 2048x2048 brush image painting onto a 1920x1080 canvas, but using a 4096x4096 canvas with the same brush I got no problems. I am thinking the target's resolution is too low for the drawing of the pixels into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if your target's resolution (image texture being painted on) is low, it will have problems interpreting the projected pixels. If you instead paint on a larger image of at least double the resolution, you will get a better result.

Here I made a 2048x2048 brush, set to repeat like yours and painted into a 4096x4096 target image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Craig, that seems to be the issue, thanks for responding